# Bookmarking Others Questions in any Stack Exchange

Tags: support, bookmarks

If I bookmark a question posted by userA, will I receive, in the future notifications of userA's new posts?

Comment: no, it's not a user follow feature.

Comment: No. You bookmark a post, not a user. Anyway bookmarking doesn't notify you of anything. You can `follow` posts though

Comment: You could follow a users questions or answers tab over RSS. You'd need an RSS client of course

Comment: [Thunderbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Thunderbird) includes a reasonable RSS reader (though there isn't a global "mailbox" - each RSS feed must be checked for new content).